# gitbook favicon plugin not working

Tags: plugins, favicon, gitbook

i put file in assets image directory. The file path is correct for sure. favicon is generated by favicon software. the file should also be right. My gitbook server also say install plugin favicon success. after i visit website, i realize my favicon is not changed as favicon.ico".  It is still old gitbook favicon. I clear the cache and i even use different brower. there is nothing changed..

Everything looks correct but just not working.

```
   {
    "plugins": ["favicon"]
}

"pluginsConfig": {
    "favicon":{
        "shortcut": "assets/images/favicon.ico",
        "bookmark": "assets/images/favicon.ico",
        "appleTouch": "assets/images/apple-touch-icon.png",
        "appleTouchMore": {
            "120x120": "assets/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png",
            "180x180": "assets/images/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png",
        }
    }
}
```

i even use another gitbook favicon plugin

```
{
"plugins" : ["custom-favicon"],
"pluginsConfig" : {
    "favicon": "path/to/favicon.ico"
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Try to write `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico">`
inside your head tag